Lean 4: Function that switches on Proposition
Lean4, I need to define a function that switches depending on a Proposition and to reason about that function.
The following  file shows my attempt to do that. How can I show th1 and th2 or define h in an other way, such that I can?
open Classical

universe u v
axiom α : Type u
axiom β : Type v

axiom f:α → β
axiom g:α → β

axiom p:α → Prop

noncomputable def h (a:α) := match (propDecidable (p a)) with
  | isTrue ht => f a
  | isFalse hf => g a

theorem th1 (a:α) (h0:p a) : h a = f a := sorry
theorem th2 (a:α) (h0:¬ (p a)) : h a = g a := sorry

Broader context: As an exercise and a study object, I want to create a standalone proof of the Bernstein-Schröder theorem

There's a tactic split that lets you analyze the cases of a match, available here once you've unfolded h (which is the simp only [h]).
theorem th1 (a:α) (h0:p a) : h a = f a := by
  simp only [h]
  split 
  case h_1 => rfl
  case h_2 h1 _ => exfalso; exact h1 h0

theorem th2 (a:α) (h0:¬ (p a)) : h a = g a := by
  simp only [h]
  split
  case h_1 hp _ => exfalso; exact h0 hp
  case h_2 => rfl

It's unusual to match on an element of Decidable and expose the constructors. You're likely to have a better time if you just use if-then-else, which is like a case split on Decidable props but with better support.
noncomputable def h' (a:α) := if p a then f a else g a

theorem th1' (a:α) (h0: p a) : h' a = f a := by
  simp [h', h0]

theorem th2' (a:α) (h0: ¬p a) : h' a = g a := by
  simp [h', h0]


With the original definition, I need to have cases on isTrue and isFalse, instead of h_1 and h_2, but otherwise this works for me. Thank you also for the hint on if / then /else.
